# Indicattion for the first ID appearance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 2 columns: date and ID. I need to add some sort of flag that would indicate at what date the ID shows for the first time:

Date        ID

2/24/2015   1

2/23/2015   1

2/22/2015   2

2/21/2015   2

2/20/2015   3

2/19/2015   3

2/18/2015   2

2/17/2015   2

2/16/2015   4

2/15/2015   4

2/14/2015   4

2/13/2015   1

2/12/2015   1

2/11/2015   1

To

Date ID Flag

2/24/2015   1

2/23/2015   1

2/22/2015   2

2/21/2015   2

2/20/2015   3

2/19/2015   3   1

2/18/2015   2

2/17/2015   2   1

2/16/2015   4

2/15/2015   4

2/14/2015   4   1

2/13/2015   1

2/12/2015   1

2/11/2015   1   1

Comment: Don't use `date` as a column name. It is already used as a type name.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ztable u
SET zflag = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM ztable nx
   WHERE nx.zid = u.zid
   AND nx.zdate < u.zdate
   );
```

Comment: Thanks, how can you do it in select statement?